# Adding treatment groups via metadata to Seurat object?

Tags: scrnaseq, seurat, single-cell

I'd like to add metadata to 6 individual Seurat objects so that after I merge the objects into one, I can later label or split by using these identifiers. For example, I'd like to append an age group and then interval across these 6 objects. For adding an interval, I've tried using the below:

> AddMetaData(control, metadata = 1hr, col.name = Interval)

However, this error will occur:

```
Error in .AddMetaData(object = object, metadata = metadata, col.name = col.name) : 
  object '1hr' not found
```

Appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have fed `"1h"` to your function call but you fed `1h` instead. The latter is looking for an object with that name and as the error shows, there is no such object.